# How to pass a javascript variable into a groovy block

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

I need to manage a groovy list object in my javascript function.
I have a groovy block into a javascript function. 
I tried with this:

```
var obj = ${mediaObjectInstanceList as grails.converters.JSON}[index];
```

and this:

```
var obj = ${mediaObjectInstanceList.get(index)};
```

but both are wrong. In the second I would specify the "index" int javascript variable out of the groovy block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by injecteer, you can't do that. Mostly because :

- groovy blocks are executed server side : they can't be aware of variables in javascript only know by the browsers.
- javascript is executed client side, ie. browsers don't know the variable `mediaObjectInstanceList` (only known by your grails application).

Two (main) solutions :

- you don't know your index when the page is generated (no params in your request) => You have to generate the whole array server side (groovy) to be available at client side (javascript).

  var mediaObjectInstanceListInJS = new Array( ${mediaObjectInstanceList.collect { it as JSON}.join(',')} );
  var someVal = mediaObjectInstanceListInJS[index];
- you already have the index server side (with params in your request) => you can get in groovy block only your selected object :

  var someVal = ${mediaObjectInstanceListInJS[params.index] as JSON} ;

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't think about the two different elaboration times (server side for groovy and client side for javascript).
Basically I wanted to create a object list to pass to the controller including only the checked object.
I solved the problem naming the checkboxes with check_<objID> and then creating a list of checked ids using javascript and adding it as a hidden form input. So, the controller's method can reload the objects using the ids in the list.
Thanks for have enlightened me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in a way you defined it.

Though, there are lots of possibilities to accomplish that.

One of them is to define a JS-variable and fill it with groovy model values:

```
var myArray = new Array( 
<g:each in="${mediaObjectInstanceList}" var="obj" status="ix">
  ${status ? ',' : ''} '${obj}'
</g:each>
);
```

then you can traverse this array in JS using plain subscript notation:

```
var someVal = myArray[ index ];
```

Comment: `var myArray = new Array( ${mediaObjectInstanceList.collect { it as JSON}.join(',')} );` ?

Comment: this might not work, if one ``obj`` contains a single quote.  My JS is very rusty, but would not ``${new JSON(["q'q",'dq"dq']).toString() }`` suffice?

Comment: why would I need to convert the object into JSON to be converted to String again? In order to waste the resources only? To fight the single quote a simple `replaceAll()` would suffice

Comment: I couldn't solve my issue like that unfortunately. I needed to create a second object list excluding some of them and then passing it as a form input value. But unfortunately groovy works only with strings, it isn't possible to pass a list of object. I found another solution that I've explained as a comment in the under answer.
Thanks for your contributions!