# Insert a javascript variable in createLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I would like to pass the value of the variable orderSlipID to this createLink.

```
function showOrderedItems() {       
    $.ajax({
        url: '${createLink(action:'listOrderedMenu', id:orderSlipID)}', 
        success: function(data) {
          $('#orderedlist').html(data);                                                     
        }
    });
};
```

this orderSlipID comes from a seperate GSP. I would like to set the id of the createLink to the id of the button that I click.

Here's my other GSP:

```
<g:each  in="${orderSlipInstanceList}" var="os">
    <div class="table" data-slip="${os.id}">${os.tableNumber}</div>
</g:each>
<script>
    $('.table').click(function(){
    orderSlipID = parseInt($(this).attr('data-slip'));
    showOrderedItems(); 
 });
</script>
```

So when I click a table it will save the id of the orderedSlip to orderSlipID and pass it to createLink to display the new content of #orderedlist.

Comment: orderSlipID is coming from where? Server or client? If client, impossible since the server code does not run at that point in time. Can't you just send up the data in the GET data like you would for any other GET request?

Comment: And as I was saying, You need to pass up the id with `data` in the Ajax request.

Comment: Another post about the same subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044925/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-into-a-groovy-block/22046954#22046954

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `orderSlipID` in the jQuery method as an argument

```
<script>
    $('.table').click(function(){
        var orderSlipID = parseInt($(this).attr('data-slip'));
        showOrderedItems(orderSlipID);
    });
</script>
```

and change in ajax

```
function showOrderedItems(orderSlipID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '${createLink(action:'listOrderedMenu')}', 
        data: {id: orderSlipID},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#orderedlist').html(data);                                                     
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have solved the problem by assigning a url for each button

```
     <g:each  in="${orderSlipInstanceList}" var="os">
       <div class="table" data-url="${createLink(action: 'listOrderedMenu', id:"${os.id}")}">${os.tableNumber}</div>
     </g:each>
```

and by using a url variable:

```
  var urlSlip = '${createLink(action:'listOrderedMenu', id:11)}';
```

and changed the $.ajax url to

```
  url:urlSlip
```